# How to use "In the span of"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing an essay regarding the concept of Carpe Diem and I'd like to start my introduction with the following sentence:

> "In the span of the universe, a human life is an incredibly short period of time."

I feel like I'm using "in the span of" wrong. 
What I'm trying to get at is that the length of a human life is a very short amount of time when compared to the lifespan of the universe.

Any help regarding the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could say "Compared to..."  "Compared to the age of the universe, a human life-span is incredibly short."

Answer (score 2):

Your statement could be considered accurate, although a bit ambiguous, as I think the first thing most people would think of upon hearing "the span of the universe" is the spatial span of it. If you said "In the time-span of the universe, a human life is incredibly short" or ""Compared with the time-span of the universe, a human life is incredibly short", it would be a little clearer.

Compare: the various definitions of span: 
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/span
with the much more specific (and thus less ambiguous) definition of time-span:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/timespan